# Cannot send and receive udp message in same program

Tags: python, sockets

I am able to send and receive UDP messages in separate programs, but I'm not able to do the same task in one program.

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.178"
UDP_PORT = 8888
msg = 'test'

print "UDP target IP: ", UDP_IP
print "UDP target PORT: ", UDP_PORT
print "Message: ", msg

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(msg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


UDP_IP2 = "192.168.1.198"

sock.bind((UDP_IP2, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

With this program, I am able to send UDP messages, however, I am not able to receive any messages from the other machine.

What am I doing wrong?


Thanks in advance,

Mikkel

Comment: you probably need to have some event loop calling [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you try to bind socket addr after sending, what's wrong.
Address can be bound to socket only *before* any data transfer.

If there is no explicit bind OS sets any *free (unused)* port number in range [1024, 65535] on first `.send()/.recv()` call.

Next, socket can be bound only to single IP (except special case '0.0.0.0' which means "all host's interfaces").